Functionally Hausdorff P-spaces that aren't regular
Let $X$ be a Functionally Hausdorff P-space.
I know that $X$ is Totally separated, because, given $x, y \in X$ such that $x \neq y$, exists a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0, f(y) = 1$. Now observe that $A = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f^{-1}([0, \frac{1}{n}[) = f^{-1}(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}[0, \frac{1}{n}[) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a clopen set in $X$ verifiying that $x \in A$ and $y \notin A$. This means that $X$ is totally separated.
Note: Every Totally separated space is Functionally Hausdorff. So, a P-space is Totally separated if, and only if, it is Functionally Hausdorff.
I wondered what other properties could $X$ satisfy, like being regular.
And I tried to think about it as follows:
Given a non-empty closed subset of $X$, let's denote as $C$, and a point $x \in X \setminus C$. For each $y \in C$, exists $U_y$ clopen subset of $X$ such that $x \in U_y$ and $y \notin U_y$. Now taking $A = \bigcap_{y\in C}U_y$, we have that $x \in A$, $C \subseteq X \setminus A$ and $A$ is closed. We know that if $C$ is countable, then $A$ is open, but if $C$ isn't countable, then we can't assure that $A$ is open under this reasoning.
After this, I thought that there are examples of P-spaces that are Functionally Hausdorff, but aren't regular. However, I haven't found any. Does anyone know an example of a space verifying this (Functionally Hausdorff + P-space + $\neg$regular)?
Incorporation from the comments:
There is a P-space that isn't regular which has Functionally Hausdorff pending to be determined in $\pi$-Base (therefore, it is also unknown if it is Totally separated or not). See: Misra's subspace of $E_0$.

Pi-base doesn't have an example.

Yeah. However, there is a P-space that isn't regular which has Functionally Hausdorff pending to be determined in $\pi$-Base. Misra's subspace of $E_0$.

Let $X$ be a $P$-space with a topology $\tau$ which is functionally Hausdorff. Let $D\subseteq X$ be dense but not open and consider the topology $\tau'$ generated by $\tau\cup{D}$. This will be a non-regular topology which is still functionally Hausdorff and a $P$-space (the former because it refines a totally separated topology so it is totally separated itself)

Thanks, Alessandro! Great answer. Would you like to submit it as the answer to the question, instead of as a comment??

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a functionally Hausdorff $P$-space. If $\tau$ is already not regular we are done, otherwise consider a dense but not open $D\subseteq X$ and let $\tau'$ be the topology on $X$ generated by $\tau\cup\{D\}$.
Then $(X,\tau')$ is a $P$-space (easy), it is not regular  (also easy, see Exercise I.8.20 on page  140 of Bourbaki's General Topology, Part 1 for more informations) and it is still functionally Hausdorff, since by the body of the question for $P$-spaces  being functionally Hausdorff is the same as being totally separated, so that being functionally Hausdorff is inherited by finer $P$-space topologies.
For reference I knew of this idea from the beginning of Section 3 of this paper by Misra, which is a useful reference to keep in mind when studying $P$-spaces and their separation/compactness properties (the subspace of $E_0$ mentioned in the question is also featured in this paper)

Again, thank you very much, Alessandro. Not only you have answered to the question, but, after reading and my comprehension process, I have also learnt new useful ideas.
